# how add answers into table in quiz project?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

i have created quiz project. i select question from database limit 1,1. user see in each pahe 1 question and 4 option. i want when click option radio button valuse of button must set in table below options. for user to be aware which answer was clicked when at the end exam. when user decide to sumbit exam he must clikc ajax button under answerlist table and all answers must be instert into databse then user will result.

i did it, in every click on radio button values shows in table button when click next page radio button value, previosly question answer value become null.

how reslove this problem ?

```html
<html>
<head>

    <% Logger log =   Logger.getLogger("Test");%>

    <% Long qnum =     (Long) session.getAttribute("qnumer"); %>
    <% String answer = (String) session.getAttribute("answer"); %>
    <%log.info(qnum + answer); %>
    <% String [] answerqlist = new String[6] ; %>

    <%switch (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(qnum))){
        case  1:
            String a1 = answer;
            answerqlist[0]=a1;
            break;

        case  2:
            String a2 = answer;
            answerqlist[1]=a2;
            break;

        case  3:
            String a3 = answer;
            answerqlist[2]=a3;
            break;

        case  4:
            String a4 = answer;
            answerqlist[3]=a4;
            break;

        case  5:
            String a5 = answer;
            answerqlist[4]=a5;
            break;

        case  6:
            String a6 = answer;
            answerqlist[5]=a6;
            break;

    }%>

</head>
<body>
    <table   cellspacing="0" width="100%"  style="border: solid 1px;" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><%=answerqlist[0]%></td>
                <td><%=answerqlist[1]%></td>
                <td><%=answerqlist[2]%></td>
                <td><%=answerqlist[3]%></td>
                <td><%=answerqlist[4]%></td>
                <td><%=answerqlist[5]%></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope you guys got a college project. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201545/temporary-variable-save-in-jsp) from your peer. Don't create separate questions.